# Mongodb performance with long list of array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

okay I have an issue where I have a long list of array let say up to 45,000 list of strings into a mongoldb collection.

it takes some time to save into the db so I want to know if It possible to save it so other required services can make use of the data almost immediately a service like buffer.

I have searched a whole long list of materials but I'm coming up short.

please anyone with link, materials or any workaround to battle the issue thanks.

Comment: Are you adding 45000 documents to a collection, or an array of 45000 strings to one document?

Comment: the problem is the 1 time that you insert it to the database? or when you are updating it?

Comment: I am adding an array of 45000 strings to one document @seeBoot

Comment: @takis it should work both ways when either creating or updating an existing document is here any materials that covers such cases 